# How to access encapsulated value in a class from a seperate file?

Tags: python, file, class, python-3.x, encapsulation

I am working on a large python program with multiple files and I came up with a problem. I am creating 5 instances in a class from a separate file but I am not sure how to access it once it has been created. It is encapsulated as well. I will show a very simple example of what my problem is. This example will use two files, file_1 and file_2.

file_1

```
class Hello():

    def set_num(self,one,two):
        self.__first = one
        self.__second = two
```

file_2

```
import file_1
def get_it():
    I = -1
    first_one = 50
    second_one = 75
    for i in range(5):
        I+=1
        first_one = first_one*2
        second_one = second_one*1.5
        newI = "a"+str(I)
        new = file_1.Hello()
        file_1.Hello.set_num(new,first_one,second_one) 

def get_first():
    print(a1._Hello__first)
```

So I am only running the file_2, get_it(). When run it should create this (all behind the scenes):

```
a1._Hello__first = 100
a1._Hello__second = 112.5
a2._Hello__first = 200
a2._Hello__second = 168.75
.....
```

So that is where the data is supposedly stored. What I need is to access that data from file_2, I am going to create another function in file_2 that will access it.
But my question is how would I access it? 
This is the second function in file_2, it should return 100 but it gives an error:

```
def get_first():
    print(a1._Hello__first)
```

When I run that I get "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '*Hello*_first'".
So my question is, how would I access that data?

Comment: You can't make an object called `"1"`.  Just make a list and append your objects to it.

Comment: Instead of `file_1.Hello.set_num(new,first_one,second_one)`, you can simply write `new.set_num(first_one, second_one)` -- you can call the method via the instance instead of manually calling the method on the class and passing the instance as the first argument.  (I'm also not sure what you're doing with `I`.)

Comment: @BrenBarn, This is a school project, so I have no choice but to use a class. So any Ideas on how to create multiple instances?

Comment: You can use a class.  What you can't do is make an instance of your class called `"1"`.

Comment: @BrenBarn, I changed to a1, a2... but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally a good idea, when creating multiple instances of a class, to put them somewhere you can get at them, e.g. in a container like `dict` or `list`:

```
instances = [] # list to hold instances
for _ in range(5):
    first_one *= 2
    second_one *= 1.5
    new = file_1.Hello() # create instance
    new.set_num(first_one, second_one) # set number
    instances.append(new) # add to list
```

Now when you want to print them out:

```
for instance in instances:
    print(instance._Hello__first)
    print(instance._Hello__second)
```